# Sentiment analysis with predefined text

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I'm working on a sentiment analysis project in Python using  NLTK. The output of the project must show whether the given statement is positive or negative. I have succeeded in doing that, but how can I obtain an output for a neutral statement?
And is it possible to output in the form of percentages (i.e., positive %, negative %, or neutral %)?

**classifier.py**

```
import random
import preprocess
import nltk

def get_classifier():
    data = preprocess.get_data()
    random.shuffle(data)

    split = int(0.8 * len(data))

    train_set = data[:split]
    test_set =  data[split:]

    classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)

    accuracy = nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, test_set)
    print("Generated Classifier")
    print('-'*70)
    print("Accuracy: ", accuracy)
    return classifier
```

**preprocess.py**

```
import nltk.classify
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

stop_words = stopwords.words("english")

def create_word_features_pos(words):
    useful_words = [word for word in words if word not in stop_words]
    my_list = [({word: True}, 'positive') for word in useful_words]
    return my_list

def create_word_features_neg(words):
    useful_words = [word for word in words if word not in stop_words]
    my_list = [({word: True}, 'negative') for word in useful_words]
    return my_list

def create_word_features(words):
    useful_words = [word for word in words if word not in stopwords.words("english")]

    pos_txt = get_tokenized_file(u"positive-words.txt")
    neg_txt = get_tokenized_file(u"negative-words.txt")

    my_dict = dict([(word, True) for word in pos_txt if word in useful_words])
    my_dict1 = dict([(word, False) for word in neg_txt if word in useful_words])
    my_dict3 = dict([word,])
    my_dict.update(my_dict1)

    return my_dict

def get_tokenized_file(file):
    return word_tokenize(open(file, 'r').read())

def get_data():
    print("Collecting Negative Words")
    neg_txt = get_tokenized_file(u"negative-words.txt")
    neg_features = create_word_features_neg(neg_txt)

    print("Collecting Positive Words")
    pos_txt = get_tokenized_file(u"positive-words.txt")
    pos_features = create_word_features_pos(pos_txt)
    return pos_features + neg_features

def process(data):
    return [word.lower() for word in word_tokenize(data)]
```

Comment: Fix your indentations and Use proper formatting for your code

Answer (score 0):

The doc for `nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train`:

> Parameters:   labeled_featuresets – A list of classified featuresets,
>   i.e., a list of tuples (featureset, label).

This means your `train_set` is a set of tuples of `(features, label)`.

If you want to add a `neutral` type, you need to label some of your data as `neutral` otherwise there is no way for the classifier to learn this new type.

Right now you label your data as: `(word, True)` and `(word, False)`, an example of switching to 3 labels is `(word, 0)`, `(word, 1)`, `(word, 2)`

`nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.prob_classify` will return the probability of each label.

Documentation can be found here: https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.classify.html#nltk.classify.naivebayes.NaiveBayesClassifier